# Should I use multiple Router components to create multi-level navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-v4

Let's say I have the following app structure:

```
+--+--+ login
   |
   +--+ signup
   |
   +--+ inner main
      |
      +--+ settings/user
      |
      +--+ settings/app
      |
      +--+ settings/about
      |...
```

`inner` will wrap everything below it, but when I get to `/settings` I will have 3 tabs that will use a router. I want `settings` to have another wrapper for all the routes below it, so if I am logged in, and go to `www.myapp.com/settings/user` I will get `innerWrapper -> settingsWrapper -> userSettings`

Should `settings` use a Route component of their own, since I'm not sure if there is a way to keep its components wrapped in one router component setup. Doing something like this seems bad:

```
<Route path="/settings/user" {...rest} render={props => (
    <wrapper>
      <User {...props}/>
    </wrapper>
)}/>
<Route path="/settings/app" {...rest} render={props => (
    <wrapper>
      <App {...props}/>
    </wrapper>
)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In React Router V4 you put sub routes inside components.

So, in your **InnerWrapper** component, where your router is, you can have a route to the **'/settings'** page which renders the **SettingsWrapper** component:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path='/settings' component={ SettingsWrapper } />
  // Other routes
</BrowserRouter>
```

Then in your **SettingsWrapper** component, you can have sub routes which will render other components inside it:

```
<Route path='/settings/user' component={ UserSettings } />
<Route path='/settings/app' component={ AppSettings } />
```

I hope this helps.